# Adding a listener to the Dailymotion Player event when multiple players

Tags: javascript

I want to catch the event, when the users clicks on any Dailymotion video.

When there is only one video on the page, it is clear.

```
// Get access to the embedded player instance using one of the get player methods.
const callback = (state) => {
}
dailymotion
.getPlayer()
.then((player) => {
// Add an event listener to the event 'PLAYER_START'
player.on(dailymotion.events.PLAYER_START, callback)
});
```

But there are several videos.

Also there are some videos which are loaded by ajax on button click.

```
var player = dailymotion.createPlayer(iframeID, {
            video: videoSrc,
            params: {
        },
          })
          .then((player) => console.log(player));
```

How can I add the listener for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved based on the answer of @Milos Stojanovic.

```
   // Get access to all embedded player instances on the page
Promise.all(dailymotion.getAllPlayers()).then((players) => {
    // Add an event listener to each player for the 'PLAYER_START' event
    players.forEach((player) => {
        player.on(dailymotion.events.PLAYER_START, callback)
    });
})
```

For videos which are loaded by ajax on button click.

```
var player = dailymotion.createPlayer(iframeID, {
                video: videoSrc,
                params: {
            },
              })
              .then((player) => {
    player.on(dailymotion.events.PLAYER_START, callback)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
// Define the callback function
const callback = (state) => {
    alert("Received PLAYER_START event");
};

// Get access to all embedded player instances on the page
Promise.all(dailymotion.getAllPlayers()).then((players) => {
    // Add an event listener to each player for the 'PLAYER_START' event
    players.forEach((player) => {
        player.on(dailymotion.events.PLAYER_START, callback);
    });
})
.catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That didn't work, but that gave me a great tip.

Comment: I changed answer. I forgot that `.all` will return array with fulfillment values when fulfilled.

Comment: That works for the videos, which are on the page after page load. But doesn't work for the videos I upload with ajax when clicking More button. Do you know how can I listen to all the videos, even when they are embedded later on the page.

Comment: I guess you will have to go through new videos and add event listener to them when you click on More button. Don't really know how you would do it since I don't have your code base.